# Repaint Issue ON TV Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script

Can Anyone Tell Me How To Fix Repaint? On Tradinview In Pine Editor Lookahead_off Will Fix Repaint Completely Or Not? Or Is There Any Other Ways ? I've Tried Small Timeframe It Still Repaints But On Higher Timeframe It Repaints More Often Than On Lower One

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Indicator_repainting.html) first to understand why repainting occurs in the first place.

Then you can use the following [function](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) that is provided by PineCoders:

```
// Function to securely and simply call `security()` so that it never repaints and never looks ahead.
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```